# How to organize Entity Framework Core migrations (code first) with 2 different databases schema in the same project?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

So I am building an API in ASP.NET Core and I want to use Entity Framework Core with code first.

The problem I have is that I have two different database schemas (one for the Catalog database containing all client information and one for the tenants databases containing each client's app data).
I have a hard time figuring out how to organize my migrations.

Here's how I imagine things right now :

- **Api Project** : ASP.NET core project containing controllers and builds the DbContexts, getting the connection strings from the Environment variables set up in Azure.
- **Catalog Project** : Contains core business logic along with persistence code, so the CatalogDbContext code would be here along with it's migrations.
- **Tenants Project** : Contains core business logic along with persistence code, so the TenantDbContext code would be here along with it's migrations.
- **Common Project** : Contains generic code that can be reused in both Catalog and Tenant project, like a basic repository interface, etc.

The CatalogDbContext would be instantiated in the Startup.cs (Api Project) file as there's only one instance of that database while the Tenants would be instantiated probably in a filter or in the controller depending on the user session's token (we'd retrieve the associated tenant database from the catalog database).

Now I also want to use a local database if I am in a development environment rather than retrieving the connection string from the environment variables.

The thing that really confuses me is how Entity Framework Core knows where to look to generate migrations? Like if I instantiate the DbContext and link it to a SqlServer provider only in the controllers or in the Startup.cs of the Api Project, how will it work?
People recommend to set up the connection string in the OnConfiguring method of the DbContext but I don't want to be setting a static connection string in the Catalog/Tenants assembly, I want to get this info from the environment variables.

So should I be passing the connection string as a property or constructor parameter of the DbContext and simply using that property in the OnConfiguring method?

Hope this makes a bit of sense.
Thank you!

Comment: Did it solve the your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a demo multi-tenant application I created earlier, https://github.com/SamuelKoroh/AspNetCorePropertyPro

Inside of AspNetCorePropertyPro.Data project there I've both the TenantDbContext and GlobalDbContext.

The GlobalDbContext is where I manage the settings for tenants.

```
services.AddDbContext<GlobalDbContext>(c => 
  c.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

The DefaultConnection here is set to a local database on my local environment variable using secret.json(Manager User Secret) while on production(Azure App Service) the default connection if pointing to azure ms SQL.

The AspNetCorePropertyPro.Data project also contains the migrations for both DbContext.

The tenant migration is placed as a child directory inside the migrations folder generated by entityframework to achieve that use:  dotnet ef migrations add {tenant-migration-name} -o Migrations/Tenants -c TenantDbContext -s ../AspNetCorePropertyPro.Api/AspNetCorePropertyPro.Api.csproj

dotnet ef migrations add {migration-name} -c TenantDbContext -s ../AspNetCorePropertyPro.Api/AspNetCorePropertyPro.Api.csproj to run the migration against a client.

dotnet ef database update -c GlobalDbContext -s ../AspNetCorePropertyPro.Api/AspNetCorePropertyPro.Api.csproj to run migration against the global context

dotnet ef database update -c GlobalDbContext -s ../AspNetCorePropertyPro.Api/AspNetCorePropertyPro.Api.csproj to run migration against the global context

-o = output directory.

-c = dbcontext to perform the migration if more than one exists.

-s = the path to the startup project.

Note services.AddDbContext(); doesn't reference any database settings at design time, this is done at runtime depending on the tenant access the system.

```
 protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            var conn =  _tenant.ConnectionString;
            //var conn = @"Server=(localDB)\MSSqlLocalDB; database=TenantOne; Integrated Security=true";
            //optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(conn);
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(conn);
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }
```

Comment: Question, does Azure override your connection string in appsettings by defaut or do you have to do something in particluar? Thanks

Comment: You have to set your environmental variables on azure app service appsetting for your api